# How do I manage CSS framework to use only one component in my React App

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, materialize

I have a large and portfolio that I am building in React and I really want to avoid the process of rebuilding the entire project because of a styling framework.. Here is the situation: I am exporting App.js for the root of the project and because I have my components specifically built to use external data I chose to write this part of my app in the App.js instead of as another component.

My Materialize CSS Framework is what is causing the issues, I need it to display my className 'card' correctly, but when I use Materialize Framework it ruins the rest of my page. How can I designate my framework to ONLY work with one div object for example

How can I say "Only use Materialize CSS Framework for App3"

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Header from './components/Header';
import About from './components/About';
import Resume from './components/Resume';
import Portfolio from './components/Portfolio';
import Testimonials from  './components/Testimonials';
import ContactUs from './components/ContactUs';
import Footer from './components/Footer';
import resumeData from './resumeData';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Header resumeData={resumeData}/>
        <About resumeData={resumeData}/>
        <Resume resumeData={resumeData}/>
        <Portfolio resumeData={resumeData}/>

  <div className="App3">
     <div class="card" style={{ width: '18rem' }}>
      <div class="card-image waves-effect waves-block waves-light">
      <img class="activator" src={weatherImage}></img>
    </div>
  <div class="card-content">          
  <span class="card-title activator grey-text text-dark-4">


<i class="material-icons-right"><img src={iconUrl}></img></i></span>
   </div>
    <div class="card-reveal">
    <span class="card-title activator grey-text text-dark-4">{this.state.cityName}
<i class="material-icons-right"><img src={iconUrl}></img></i></span>

      <div className="row">
        <div className="col s6 offset-s3">
          <form onSubmit={this.searchCity}>
        <input type="text" id="city" placeholder="City..."></input>
        </form>
      </div>
      </div>
      </div>

      </div>
      </div>
```

`

```
        <Testimonials resumeData={resumeData}/>
        <ContactUs resumeData={resumeData}/>
        <Footer resumeData={resumeData}/>

      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically what you want is to use scoped style like this

```
<div>
    <style scoped>
        @import "yourCssFileHere.css";
        <div class="card" style={{ width: '18rem' }}>
    </style>
</div>
```

You can get more help here http://css-tricks.com/saving-the-day-with-scoped-css/.

Comment: Thank you for the help, I ended up going through the css views and filing them each out with *important thanks to your scope suggestion I figured this out!